# PostgreSQL Chage Data Capture in Talend

Tags: postgresql, talend, change-data-capture

I need to capture PostgreSQL changes and I would prefer if it is log based.

How does tpostgresqlCDC work? Is it log/trigger based?

Is this component available on Talend open studio for data integration suit? I know it is available on the big data version, but I can seem to find it in Talend open studio for data integration?

Comment: Did you try https://help.talend.com//pages/viewpage.action?pageId=272769191#Raa37041 ? All CDC components are only available in licenced products, and not in Open Studio edition.

Comment: Thanks Corentin for getting back at me, the issue is that Talend implements CDC by using triggers, which add an estimate of 8% overhead.giving the age of the Talend project, does anyone found a work around this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except AS400 and Oracle, all Talend CDC - trigger based
plus:

- it only in subscription version
- at least in MySQL realisations - I found some wrong logic

opposite to MySQL it not so wide available, but You can try to check:

1. [Bottledwater](https://github.com/confluentinc/bottledwater-pg)
2. [wla2jjson](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json)
3. [Debezium](https://hub.docker.com/r/debezium/postgres/) , [main site](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/postgresql/)

CDC + Kafka - give real flexibility